# Extract a list of all built-in functions used in a notebook

Tags: documentation

I am writing my code documentation and need to list all the *Mathematica* built in functions I have used - explicitly written functions only. Is there a way to extract a list of all built in functions that I have used in my code?

For example

```
Insert[{a, b, c}, x, 3]
a=1
Style["this text",Bold]
Range[1,20]
b=3
a*b
```

I would require a list containing `Insert`, `Style` and `Range`.

Comment: You might also anticipate getting `List`, `Set`, and `Times`, since `a=1` for example is equivalent to `Set[a,1]`.

Comment: As noticed in comments you should probably explain what do you mean. 1) only explicitely written functions? 2) what is function

Comment: @Öskå must be v9, Kuba's answer worked for the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
systemSymbolsInNotebook[file_String] := Module[{n, cells, exprs, syms},
  n = NotebookOpen[file];
  SelectionMove[n, All, Notebook];
  cells = NotebookRead[n];
  NotebookClose[n];
  exprs = MakeExpression[First@#] & @@@ cells;
  syms = Cases[exprs, s_Symbol :> SymbolName@Unevaluated@s, {3, -1}, Heads -> True];
  Intersection[syms, Names["System`*"]]]

systemSymbolsInNotebook["test.nb"]
(* {"Bold", "Insert", "List", "Range", "Set", "Style", "Times"} *)
```

Comment: Even if OP agrees with non explicitly used functions as `Times` or `Set` I don't think `Bold` should appear there.

Comment: That's nice - +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I had a notebook with NotebookPut, Get and some other things and the results I got from using this code were {"CellChangeTimes", "List", "Rule", "TextCell"}

Comment: @LaraJordan, ah okay. I only tested it with the simple example in the question.

Answer (score 8):

```
functions[nb_] :=
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Join @@
     Extract[
      #
      ,
      Position[
       #
       ,
       x_Symbol /; Context[x] == "System`"
       ]
      ,
      HoldComplete
      ] &[
   ToExpression[Unevaluated[#], StandardForm, 
      HoldComplete] & /@ (NotebookRead@Cells[nb, GeneratedCell-> False])[[All, 1]]]
  ]
```

For your specific case, where you don't want symbols that never occur as the head of an expression, you could use the following.

```
functionsSpecific[nb_] :=
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Join @@
     Extract[
      #
      ,
      Position[
       #
       ,
       x_Symbol /; 
        Context[x] == "System`" &&
         MatchQ[SyntaxInformation[x], _[___, 
           "ArgumentsPattern" ->  _, ___]]
       ]
      ,
      HoldComplete
      ] &[
   ToExpression[Unevaluated[#], StandardForm, 
      HoldComplete] & /@ (NotebookRead@
       Cells[nb, GeneratedCell -> False])[[All, 1]]
   ]
  ]
```

For the notebook in which I am working, which contains a lot of functions, we then have

```
Complement[functions[nb], functionsSpecific[nb]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[All,Bold,False,GeneratedCell,Integer,Italic,Null]
> ```

So it seems the functions that are excluded by `functionsSpecific` are reasonable.

Comment: Nice. I forgot about `Cells`...

Comment: So this is a custom function. Do I put the filepath in place of nb_ ? When I do that I get an error message ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "
      \!\(StandardForm\`\\ecsdbn-srv-02\lara_jordan$\Cleaner Kumba\Cleaner Kumba Tool Non-Encoded Notebooks\Initialization.nb\) " and some other error messages.

Comment: @LaraJordan use `EvaluationNotebook` or other `NotebookObject`. You can set `nb = EvaluationNotebook[]` and use it on `nb` somewhere else so it will not interfere.

Comment: Great :) can't +1 again :/

Answer (score 6):

Evaluate this at the bottom of the notebook of interest:

```
Composition[
  Select[#, StringMatchQ[Evaluate[Symbol[#]]::usage, 
                         "\!\(\*RowBox[{\"" <> # <> "\", \"[\"" ~~ __] &] &,
  Intersection[#, Names["System`*"]] &,
  Union@Cases[#, _String, ∞, Heads -> True] &,
  First /@ # &,
  NotebookRead /@ # &,
  Most
  ]@Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], GeneratedCell -> False]
```

> ```
> {"Insert", "Range", "Style"}
> ```

---

To find what I've assumed is a function, I've used `Evaluate[Symbol[#]]::usage` which should show something like

```
Plot::usage
```

> ```
> Plot[f,{x,...
> ```

so I'm looking for `name ~~ [` pattern. Unfortunately, it is not bulletproof, there are symbols with different usage structure:

```
Quiet@Select[Names["System`*"], StringMatchQ[Evaluate[Symbol[#]]::usage, 
"\!\(\*RowBox[{StyleBox[" ~~ __] &]
```

> ```
> {AddTo,Condition,Decrement,Derivative,Divide,DivideBy,Dot,Equal,Factorial,Factorial2,Greater,GreaterEqual,Increment,Less,LessEqual,MessageName,NonCommutativeMultiply,Optional,Part,Pattern,PatternTest,Plus,Power,Put,PutAppend,Repeated,RepeatedNull,ReplaceAll,ReplaceRepeated,Rule,RuleDelayed,SameQ,Set,SetDelayed,Span,StringJoin,Subtract,SubtractFrom,TagSet,TagSetDelayed,TagUnset,Times,TimesBy,Unequal,UnsameQ,Unset,UpSet,UpSetDelayed}
> ```

some of them may be considered functions, some not. So it's really hard to make a proper answer without very precise definition of `function`.

Comment: `Cells` is new in _v9_. Same goes for Jacob.

Comment: @Kuba it may be nice to adapt the second piece of code in my question [list of dangerous functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364/4330) then. My answer is basically an adaptation of the first code block.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom The dangerous functions list does not care if there is `Bold` or not, it will be dropped later anyway, that's why it's a little different problem.

Comment: @Kuba yeah, thank you for reminding me that I don't really answer the question here :P. But I don't really see what symbols we should return then, short of making an explicit list of functions we don't want, like `Bold`. By the way how do you think symbols like `$MachineEpsilon` should be handled? That one does have a usage message, but your code does not find it.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I've assumed that we need only explicitely stated functions and function is a symbol with `DownValue` which is a tricky part since those are hidden.

Comment: This also causes error messages but seems to output what I need as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba Just admit it, you are expecting Mr.Wizard or Leonid to blow everything in 1 lines of code :P

Comment: @Öskå, from Leonid I would expect 2 *pages* of code which would not only find the functions but also automatically write the documentation for you :-)

Comment: @Kuba hm, the idea with the usage messages is nice. Also the `GeneratedCell-> False` is nice btw. Here is a more robust version of the first element of your composition: `StringMatchQ[ToExpression[#, InputForm, Function[Null, MessageName[#, "usage"], HoldAll]], "\!\(\*RowBox[{\"" <> # <> "\", \"[\"" ~~ __] &`

Comment: Kuba, also compare `SyntaxInformation@Extract` with `SyntaxInformation@Bold`, that may also be a nice way to differentiate.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thank you, I wasn't focusing on improving this because of (*see the edit*). Yes I think it may be a way to go. I was thinging about putting arguments by force and catching errors :P But still I think it will end with "it probably should work" because thare are no details in docs that can assure us about any behaviour, it's discouraging.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I think checking for `ArguemtnsPattern` is the most reliable way, please consider including this to your answer. :)

Comment: @SimonWoods Correct.., let's wait and see :D

Comment: @Kuba, done. I think it works quite well :).