# Produce the same color scheme as IboView

Tags: plotting, color, chemistry

I can use the following command to produce the HOMO (highest occupied molecular orbital) in chemistry:

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
cm = 72/2.54;

datapath = "ExampleData/Pyridinecarbonitrile_MO_25_29.cub";
g1 = Import[
   datapath,
   "Graphics3D",
   Contours -> {-0.02, 0.02},
   
   ContourStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.6]}, {Red, Opacity[0.6]}},
   Background -> None,
   (*MeshStyle->Gray,*)
   (*Mesh->Automatic,*)
   ImageSize -> {8 cm, 6 cm}
   ] // First
```

[image]

It looks pretty good, but compared to [IboView](http://www.iboview.org/), it's not as beautiful. Here are some images of the IboView:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This color scheme is really nice! So how do I get the same color scheme in Wolfram as IboView?

=========upgrate=========

by `Specularity` and `Lighting` function,change some

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
cm = 72/2.54;

datapath = "ExampleData/Pyridinecarbonitrile_MO_25_29.cub";
g1 = Import[
   datapath,
   "Graphics3D",
   Contours -> {-0.02, 0.02},
   
   ContourStyle -> {
     {
      RGBColor["#c593fc"],
      Opacity[0.6],
      Specularity[Lighter@RGBColor["#9053e2"], 50]
      },
     {
      RGBColor["#8ab6f4"],
      Opacity[0.6],
      Specularity[Lighter@RGBColor["#5f9bf0"], 50]
      }
     },
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
   Method -> {"RelieveDPZFighting" -> True},
   Background -> None
   (*MeshStyle->Gray,
   Mesh->Automatic*)
   ] // First
```

[image]

It's a little closer to the color scheme.Then I tried the `Glow` function

[image]

I can use `ImageData` function get image color data

```mathematica
i = Import[
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/wxyhgk/paper-picture/202207231113165.\
png"]
Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[i, "RGB"]], 1]
BubbleChart[
 Append @@@ 
  Tally[Round[
    Flatten[ImageData[ColorConvert[i, "LAB"]], 1][[All, {2, 3}]], 
    10^-1]], ColorFunction -> (LABColor[.6, ##] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BubbleSizes -> {0.01, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Perhaps this color data can be used for ContourStyle? What do I do next, I don't know

Comment: Good question. Btw, as a matter of principle, I find it a bit problematic to have `Import` statements that run code from some other place because it could be [dangerous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29364), but maybe the mods allow it.

Comment: @user293787 I wrote this code with reference to the introduction in the `Cube`(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Cube.html) section. I don't know why

Comment: You've imported the data from the external source `"https://github.com/wxyhgk/molecular/releases/download/cube/Ar-I_\
mo40.cub"`, that's the _dangerous_ part. Also, even if the data is safe, there's no guarentee that the link won't be broken in the future. It's better to use ExampleData as in document page instead.

Comment: @xzczd I see what you mean, I uploaded the Cube file to GitHub because it was not easy to upload.

Comment: @xzczd I have change datapath

Comment: I don't share the paranoia here - I regularly put code on this site that contains `Import["http`.  Uploading a file to github so it can be an example here is completely appropriate

Comment: @JasonB. The risk isn't high of course, but link breaking did happen in the past: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/167368/revisions

Comment: I'm using Mma 13.1, and this code doesn't work the same for me as it did for you. The bubbles are not arranged around the tube/ball structure at all for me. I looked at MoleculePlot3D a bit, but I don't see a PlotTheme option (or any other option) for these bubbles (sorry, I don't know what these actually are to a chemist). But maybe you could figure out the right options. But as for "what to do next", what in your mind is still insuffuciently close to the IboView version? Smoothness, labels, specularity, lighting colors, exact color specs, what?

Comment: @lericr IboView has transparency, color, and reflectivity that I can't repeat

Comment: @lericr The last bubble diagram is not that important, I'm just guessing maybe these colors are helpful