# What are the possible security breaches in CDF content?

Tags: cdf-format, security

It has been [noted on this site before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/in-a-cdf-can-i-suppress-or-avoid-this-file-contains-potentially-unsafe-dynamic) that the free [CDF player](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) is notoriously trigger-happy in declaring dynamic content to be "potentially unsafe", and forcing the user to enable dynamic content manually upon opening the CDF. This proceeds through a rather unfriendly banner and a big grey box that covers the content.

> This file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content. More details $\gg$    <kbd>Enable Dynamics</kbd>

[image: Unsafe content message]

To quote István Zachar's answer on his [canonical CDF question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/understanding-cdf), just about anything will trigger this warning:

> The security issue rises when a function is involved in the dynamic output:
>
> - with definitions
> - that changes attributes
> - with options
> - package related functions
> - `ToExpression/MakeExpression`
> - `Compress/Uncompress`

---

It seems to me that this trigger-happiness does not really serve the spirit of security protection: if *everything* causes the warning then it does not help to discriminate the truly potentially malicious files. Mostly, though, I'm puzzled as to what a file with that sort of content *could* do if allowed to roam free. I can understand that compressed content is a no-go, but what on Earth is wrong with a function with options?

So, to put this question more precisely:

- What sorts of malicious activity are these restrictions meant to prevent? How (roughly!) would they be achieved?
- More particularly, why is each of the features above a potential security risk?
- Conversely, what are the possible dangers of enabling dynamic content on a file I don't trust completely?
- How does this situation depend on whether one is running the free or Pro CDF Player, the web plugin, or full-blown Mathematica?

---

Edit: After posting this question, I was made aware of [List of dangerous functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364/5478). This is similar, but many of the functions discussed there are disabled on CDFs, and particularly on the free player. Moreover, functions with definitions and with options are *not* deemed unsafe in notebooks, so the security thresholds for the two are different, and it is relevant to know what the dangers are in CDFs. What can those notebook-safe classes do in CDFs that renders them a security liability?

Comment: At least highly related: [List of dangerous functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364/5478)

Comment: If you have `Dynamic` in your notebook/CDF you will get this warning whenever you open from a non trusted path - regardless of whether you use Mma or player pro or CDF.