# What is a simple way to enumerate all potentially unsafe dynamic objects in a notebook or cdf?

Tags: dynamic

What is a simple way to enumerate all potentially unsafe dynamic objects in a notebook or cdf document? The objects, whose presence generate an alert in a form of `Enable Dynamic` button.

It is not always clear what exactly object is related to this alert..

Comment: The term "dynamic object" has no formal definition in _Mathematica_, so it is unclear what you are asking. Please edit your question and provide an operational definition (_Mathematica_ code) for a test for objects that would satisfy your idea of dynamic object.

Comment: You may be interested in [7606](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7606/5478) or [29364](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29364/5478)