# Can't run 2 CDF documents at a time on a Windows computer

Tags: cdf-format, windows, mac-os-x

I've rolled out a few CDF's to end users.  See earlier posts: [suppress message](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/in-a-cdf-can-i-suppress-or-avoid-this-file-contains-potentially-unsafe-dynamic) and [which player platform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/cdf-player-playerpro-or-something-else).

Now, an end user reports that they can't open more than one CDF document at a time.  The player just switches documents instead of showing a second window.

I use a iMac and I can run two CDF documents at a time side by side without any problem.  This might not deliver the most objective test because I do have a full version of Mathematica running on the machine, which could affect how may CDF documents one can run at one time.

The end user runs a Windows machine.

Has anyone else run up against this?
Does anyone know of a work around?

---

Some additional information: My end user runs Windows 7 professional  version 6.1.

Comment: I'm not behind my pc so can't check but just a tip: to check what  a standalone installation of CDF player does I've installed a virtual machine in which I can test a CDF fully independent of mma. If you have a spare copy of windows around you could try that.

Comment: My post at http://www.abstractmath.org/Word%20Press/?p=4632 has two CDF documents which can be run simultaneously on my Windows 7 machine.  But I have Mathematica installed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is two copies of the same CDF running in CDF player in a virtual box. No problems at all as far as I can see. I just double-clicked on their icons and they started without a hitch.

Comment: That looks good.  Looks like I need to dig deeper into the problem.  Human error on the user end always a possibility.  I'll report back with more info.